# Add dropdown filter list to ggplot in RMarkdown HTML file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the following code on a RMarkdown script:

```
    data <- data.frame(
      anoobito = sample(2019:2023),
      diadasemana = sample(c("Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo"), 23000, replace = TRUE)
    )
    
    dia <- data %>%
      group_by(anoobito, diadasemana) %>%
      tally %>%
      mutate(diadasemana = factor(diadasemana, levels = c("Domingo","Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado")))
    
    plot <- ggplot(dia, aes(x = diadasemana, y = n, group = anoobito)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = anoobito), size = 2) +
      geom_point(aes(color = anoobito), size = 3) +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1000), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom",
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
            axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black")) +  
      labs(
        x = "Ano do Óbito", # label do eixo X
        y = "Número de Óbitos",
        caption = "**Fonte**: SIM, SMS-RJ. Dados sujeitos a alterações.") 
    
    pp <- ggplotly(plot) %>%
      layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.25, y = -0.4))
```

As you can see, the plot lines overlay eachother. What I want to do is add a filter button on a dropdown list format so when I filter the year (anoobito), I get the plot according to that year. The legend should also disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed your plot in an [interactive Shiny document](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/interactive-docs/). In your Rmd file, add the line `runtime: shiny`.

```
---
title: "A Shiny Document"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

Then you can create a Shiny app with a dropdown filter like below. Insert the dropdown menu in your `ui` using `selectInput`. Then in your `server`, have your plot filter by year `dia %>% filter(anoobito == input$years) %>% ...`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)


# data
data <- data.frame(
  anoobito = sample(2019:2023),
  diadasemana = sample(c("Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado", "Domingo"), 23000, replace = TRUE)
)

dia <- data %>%
  group_by(anoobito, diadasemana) %>%
  tally %>%
  mutate(diadasemana = factor(diadasemana, levels = c("Domingo","Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado")))


# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("years", label = "Year:", choices = unique(data$anoobito), selected = 2019),
    plotOutput("my_plot")
  )

# server
server <- function(input, output){
    output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
      dia %>% 
        filter(anoobito == input$years) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = diadasemana, y = n, group = 1)) +
        geom_line(linewidth = 2) +
        geom_point(size = 3) +
        theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1000), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1))) +
        theme(legend.position = "bottom",
              axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
              axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black")) +  
        labs(
          x = "Ano do Óbito", 
          y = "Número de Óbitos",
          caption = "**Fonte**: SIM, SMS-RJ. Dados sujeitos a alterações.")
    })
  }

# run app
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server, options = list(height = 700))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Here is another solution using `plotly` package. You can add the dropdown in your `layout` and filter your data using `transform` parameter in `plot_ly`. You can also knit the output as an html.

```
library(plotly)

dia |>
  mutate(anoobito = as.factor(anoobito)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  arrange(diadasemana) |> 
  plot_ly(x=~diadasemana, y=~n, 
          type="scatter", mode="lines+markers",
          transforms = list(
            list(
              type = 'filter',
              target = ~anoobito,
              operation = '=',
              value = unique(dia$anoobito)[1]
            )
          )
  ) |> 
  layout(
    yaxis = list(range = c(0,1000), title = "Número de Óbitos"),
    xaxis = list(title = "Ano do Óbito"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        type = 'dropdown',
        active = 0,
        buttons = lapply(unique(dia$anoobito), 
                         \(x) list(method = "restyle",
                                   args = list("transforms[0].value", x),
                                   label = x)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. But is there any way I can do that without using shiny? I need to knit the .Rmd to an HTML file and I can't seem to do that when I'm working with shiny.

Comment: @Lana Meijinhos I've made some edits to answer. Does this help?